# Multiple Files Download Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, get, rxjs

I'm trying to implement download of multiple files using Angular 2 and RxJS.
Unfortunately there is no related threads.

Lets take maximum amount of files that can be downloaded at a time is equal to 3.

As I understand we need to send 3 separate requests on by one with or without timeout.

And here I stuck...this is working only for 1 of 3 selected files.

This `window.open(blobUrl, '_self')` inside map is dump ofc, as well as code below. It is only a scratch, let's focus on the issue.

```
exportFiles() {
 const selected = this.selectedItems;
  selected.map(x => {
  const blobUrl = this.blobsApi.getBlobUrl(x, true);
  const doc: any = document;
  window.open(blobUrl, '_self');
 })
}
```

What I tried to do:

1. Interval *(didn't help)*
2. Observables *(probably made mistakes or it just didn't fit here)*
3. `window.open(blobUrl, '_blank')`

`selectedItems` is an array of objects where each objects contains next data:

```
id: string;
name: string;
type: string;
ownerName: string;
```

Comment: Ca you try with window.open(blobUrl, '_blank');

Comment: You need to call `.subscribe` not `.map` for one thing.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Tried before, not working
@AluanHaddad `.subscribe` wont work due to `this.selectedItems` type

Comment: what is this.selectedItems

Comment: @FanCheung it is an array of objects where each object contains next data

      `id: string;`
      `name: string;`
      `type: string;`
      `ownerName: string;`
      ....